# Solving exponential equation with unknown on both sides

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am having trouble solving the equation

$$3e^{−x+2} = 5e^{x-1}$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: take the natural logarithm of both sides!

Comment: hint: Try making the problem unnecessarily difficult by turning it into a quadratic equation.

Comment: @JohnJoy um... I think you should either take out the part "unnecessarily difficult" or remove that comment altogether and make it an answer.

Comment: @SImple Art needs to lighten up a little bit.

Comment: @JohnJoy LoL, ok.

Answer (score 14):

HINT:

Take log in both sides to find $$\ln3+(-x+2)=\ln5+x-1$$

Comment: @user303134, See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Laws_of_Logarithms

Answer (score 6):

> $$3e^{−x+2} = 5e^{x-1}$$
>   Taking the natural $\log$ of both sides gives:
>   $$\ln (3e^{−x+2}) = \ln(5e^{x-1})$$
>   $$\ln3+(2-x) = \ln5+(x-1) ~~~(\text{ since } \ln(ab)=\ln a + \ln b).$$
>   So $$\ln 3 - \ln 5+3=2x.$$
>   But $\ln\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=\ln a -\ln b$. 
>   $$\therefore x=\frac{1}{2}\Big(3+\ln\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\Big).$$

Answer (score 4):

we have $\frac{3}{5}=e^{2x-3}$ by the power rule and then $\ln(\frac{3}{5})=2x-3$ can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You can also make the equation much simpler just by remembering your properties of exponents:
$$3e^{−x+2} = 5e^{x-1}$$
$$3e^{−x}e^{2} = 5e^{x}e^{-1}$$
multiply across by *e*
$$3e^{-x}e^{3}=5e^{x}$$
multiply across by $e^{x}$ and divide by $5$, take the natural log of both sides...
$$3e^{3} = 5e^{2x}$$
Now you've got the $x$ on one side, :) rest ain't so bad
$$\frac{3}{5}e^{3} = e^{2x}$$
$$\ln(\frac{3}{5}e^{3}) = \ln(e^{2x})$$
$$\ln(\frac{3}{5}e^{3}) = 2x$$
$$\therefore x = \frac{1}{2}\ln(\frac{3}{5}e^{3})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3e^{-x+2} = 5e^{x-1}$$
$$\frac{3e^2}{e^x} = \frac{5e^x}{e^1}$$
$$\dots = \dots$$